# VS2010 - Unable to view variable value when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1

Recently I installed VS 11 Developer preview and since when my existing VS 2010 has been giving me some problems.

I have created a small console application in C# that makes use of .NET 4.0, nothing fancy - basically it creates a string variable and writes it to the console. This has nothing to do with code, but rather Visual Studio. Because of the following that happens afterwards:

I am unable to view any information about the variable when debugging within Visual Studio. When I start the debugger (which is in debug mode), the application starts and breaks at the given break point but, when it breaks, I am unable to view any information about any variable (view the value of the string value).

Even when I drag the variable into the Watch window it states the following:

> Unable to evaluate the expression.

Why is this and how can I fix this?

Comment: So why the -1? Could you please give a reason?

Comment: +1 for fedback - there's nothing wrong with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by re-installing VS 2010.

Many thanks for all the feedback!